# Complexity measures for scala code are not showing in sonarqube

Tags: scala, sonarqube, code-complexity

Am analyzing my scala code with sonarqube but its not showing complexity options in measures tab. I have also added a python and javascript project and they are showing complexity in measures.
Here is my `sonar-project.properties` file

```
sonar.projectKey=my-scala-project
sonar.projectName=Scala Project
sonar.sources=src/main/scala
sonar.scala.coverage.reportPaths=target/scala-2.12/scoverage-report/scoverage.xml
```

How can i get complexity for my scala code in sonarqube analysis report?

Comment: It probably would be better to report this to the plugin authors.